# How to model time series data in cassandra when data has non-uniform generation rate?

Tags: cassandra, time-series, data-modeling, cassandra-3.0

I am planning to migrate data from my existing database (Postgres) to Cassandra. Here is a brief overview of the system:

- Current data set size is around 2 Billion
- Each data point represents an event. Properties of this event are - `user_id`, `event_name`, `timestamp`
- This data is coming from a finite set of sources - For the sake of simplicity let's assume 3 different sources S1, S2, S3 - all of them pushing in a Kafka Topic. This cassandra microservice is consuming data from this topic.
- The rate of data coming from S1, S2 and S3 is different. Assume S1 is pushing 1 event for a single user every minute, S2 is pushing 1 event for each user every 15 minutes and S3 is pushing single event for each user every 1 hour.
- There are two types of queries this system should support

  - Get latest event for a given user
  - Get list of events for a given user and date range (This data range can have diff of at most 30 days)

I am trying to model this data using few different approaches.

- Partition data for a single user into monthly buckets. For this additional parameters `timestamp_year`, `timestamp_month` are added. `timestamp` is used a cluster key.

  - *Pros*: Less than 10ms write latency. Max partition size is around ~60MB (working good for cassandra 3.11). Get latest event is working in less than 10ms (99.999 percentile).
  - *Cons*: Getting month level data is slow because of too much data being read from a single partition. If i put limit on number of records being fetched (let's say 10000) the latency improves. Partition size is non-uniform because of different rate of data from 3 different sources.

I have tried using weekly buckets instead of monthly buckets and pagination to improve on other parameters. But this is something i am not able to sort out *Partition size is non-uniform because of different rate of data from 3 different sources.*

How can i keep partition size consistent (almost) in such a data model? Ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical problem and there are no easy solutions to make partition size uniform. If you can predict the rate of ingestion per user, probably you can have different buckets of users, such as, high, medium and low ingestion users.

Depending on the type, the time bucket would be different. For a high ingestion user, partition means a day and for a low ingestion user, partition means a month.

For speeding up your month query on a high ingestion user, you can run parallel queries of 30 days and see if it helps to optimize your query time.